# Emulator always Infinite Refreshing the project

Tags: react-native, android-studio

I faced a problem in emulator, it can't start the project and infinite refresh the project

Comment: that's maybe cause your code . please share your 'app.js' or index.js code.

Comment: i add the app.js code in this link because it is so long
https://codepen.io/mona90/pen/poEayqP?editors=1010